# Extending a generic argument to a Java Function

Tags: java, function, generics

Here is a class

```
public static class Base {
  public int b1;
}
```

Here is a Consumer function

```
public static Consumer<Base> consumer = (t) -> {
System.out.println("" + t.b1);};
```

This is the calling sequence:

```
Base base1 = new Base();
consumer.accept(base1);
```

This is what I expect.

If I change the consumer to accept extensions of Base:

```
public static Consumer<? extends Base> consumer = (t) -> {
  System.out.println("" + t.b1);};
```

Then the same calling sequence doesn't compile. The compiler complaining that the capture of the consumer is not applicable to argument Base

Base surely extends Base??

If instead of a Consumer I define a method:

```
static <T extends Base> void accept(T param) {}
```

This method can be called with base1 without compiler error.

Comment: A `Consumer<? extends Base>` would accept a *specific* subclass of `Base` - not *any* subclass - but the compiler doesn't know which specific subclass, so it will only allow you to pass `null` as the parameter.

Comment: Sure it does. 
consumer.accept(base1) refers to an object instance that is of class Base. It is in the code, the compiler does have it.

Comment: I did some further digging. If I replace 'extends' with 'super' it works. I even can invoke it with a subclass of Base. Obliviously this is the intent.

Comment: `Consumer<? extends Base> consumer = (SubclassOfBase t) -> /* something specific to SubclassOfBase */;` would also be a legal assignment. But then `consumer.accept(new Base())` has to be forbidden, because the consumer needs a `SubclassOfBase` but gets a `Base`. The reason is works with `Consumer<? super Base>` is that type means "a consumer to which it is safe to pass a `Base`: it's a *consumer of `Base`s*. This is explained in the dupe.